# Python generic Container?

Tags: python

It can someone be convenient to group variables under a given object.

My use case is tensorflow, where you often have to define a graph first and then feed it with actual data.  To avoid getting the names of the graph variables jumbled up with those of the data variables, it's useful to group them all under an object.  What I've been doing is:

```
g = lambda: None
g.iterator = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train)).batch(minibatch_size).make_initializable_iterator()
g.x_next, g.y_next = g.iterator.get_next()
g.data_updates = g.x_data.assign(g.x_next), g.y_data.assign(g.y_next)
```

Except that when you use `lambda: None` your coworkers tend to get angry and confused.

Is there an alternative that provides equally clean syntax but uses something that is more obviously a container than `lambda: None`?

I first tried making them all static members of a class, but the problem is that static members cannot reference other static members.  `g=object()` would be nice but doesn't allow you to assign attributes.

Comment: like a dictionary?

Comment: Like a dictionary, but without the clunkiness of `g['iterator']`

Comment: Why not define your own class?

Comment: Seems like overkill to define a class with no methods and only public attributes which will only be instantiated once.

Comment: How about using [`types.SimpleNamespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace)?

Comment: If you inherit from `object` you already have a bunch of extremely useful methods.

Comment: @Aran-Fey BINGO!  If you put that as the answer I'll mark it solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If it's not worth defining a dedicated class, you can use [`types.SimpleNamespace`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace), which is a class specifically designed to do nothing but hold attributes.

```
g = types.SimpleNamespace()
g.iterator = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train)).batch(minibatch_size).make_initializable_iterator()
g.x_next, g.y_next = g.iterator.get_next()
g.data_updates = g.x_data.assign(g.x_next), g.y_data.assign(g.y_next)
```